# Use offset or rawoffset to compute time?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm using a javascript library which relies upon the timezone offset to set the current time. The offset is set on the server using Java. This code :

At time of running this code (17:27) :

```
package com.fmr.fc.portlet.globalclock;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a (E)");     
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

        df2.setTimeZone(tz);
        System.out.println(df2.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        System.out.println(df2.format(calendar.getTime()));

        System.out.println(tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis())/ 1000.0
                 / 60.0
                 / 60.0 + "");

        System.out.println(tz.getRawOffset() / 1000.0
                 / 60.0
                 / 60.0 + "");

    }

}
```

The output is :

```
09:27 AM (Wed)
09:27 AM (Wed)
-7.0
-8.0
```

It seems to me I should use the raw offset but the method "getOffset" adds the day light saving time to the raw offset to compute the offset which is why it reads -7 instead of -8 .

-8 is correct since I the correct time for "America/Los_Angeles" is 09:27 AM (Wed) : -8 hours IST. But it seems incorrect that I am not also taking into account the daylight savings even though it adding 1 to -8 is -7 : which is an incorrect time ?

Should I just use the rawoffset to determine the current hour ? Will I encounter issues at some point in time when daylight savings is turned off ?

Currently I cannot use JodaTime in codebase.

Comment: You might want to remove the Javascript tag. Java != Javascript

Comment: @Jonathon Done, I thought it might be useful to provide some context into how im using the offset

Comment: When I look up world time, I see that LA is currently at -7. Why are you saying this is wrong? (Side note: if you have international clients, use the browser's time zone or let them choose.)

Comment: @Harald because System.out.println(df2.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis())); prints -8 hours and current los angeles time based on https://www.google.ie/search?q=currnet+los+angeles+time&oq=currnet+los+angeles+time&aqs=chrome..69i57.4383j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 is -8 hours no -7 hours

Comment: How about timeamddate.com/worldclock ? It clearly states that currently LA is at -7.

Comment: @Harald So https://www.google.ie/search?q=currnet+los+angeles+time&oq=currnet+los+angeles+time&aqs=chrome..69i57.4383j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 is wrong ?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you get when you follow the link you gave. I get PDT which, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone , is UTC -7. :-/